# calling fortran subroutines from c++

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, cmake, fortran

I'd like to call Fortran subroutines from C++. Since my program needs to include some libraries from deal.ii (Differential Equations Analysis Library), I use CMake to create the makefile. My questions now are the following:

- What changes does CMakeLists.txt need to be able to link Fortran files?
- Do I have to include the used Fortran files explicitly in the C++ files as well, or is it enough to give the corresponding function prototypes at the beginning of the C++ code?

Thanks a lot in advance!
Seb

PS.:
Here is the current CMakeLists.txt:

```
##
#  CMake script for the SIMP program:
##

# Set the name of the project and target:
SET(TARGET "SIMP")

# Declare all source files the target consists of:
SET(TARGET_SRC
  ${TARGET}.cc
  # You can specify additional files here!
  )

# Usually, you will not need to modify anything beyond this point...

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.8)

FIND_PACKAGE(deal.II 8.0 QUIET
  HINTS ${deal.II_DIR} ${DEAL_II_DIR} ../ ../../ $ENV{DEAL_II_DIR}
  )
IF(NOT ${deal.II_FOUND})
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "\n"
    "*** Could not locate deal.II. ***\n\n"
    "You may want to either pass a flag -DDEAL_II_DIR=/path/to/deal.II to cmake\n"
    "or set an environment variable \"DEAL_II_DIR\" that contains this path."
    )
ENDIF()

DEAL_II_INITIALIZE_CACHED_VARIABLES()
PROJECT(${TARGET})
DEAL_II_INVOKE_AUTOPILOT()
```

Comment: Calling Fortran from C and C++ has been discussed many times here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-iso-c-binding

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeForFortranExample

If you're using gfortran, the only thing you need from that is

```
enable_language(Fortran)
```

The get_filename_component part checks that you have compiler that exists.  Quite useful to know which one it is picking, especially if have gfortran, g95 and ifort installed.

Answer (score 0):

Now I use the following CMakeLists.txt file and it works.

```
##
#  CMake script for the SIMP program:
##

# Set the name of the project and target:
set (TARGET "SIMP")
set (CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER "gfortran")
set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2 -m32")
set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG   "-O0 -g -m32")
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG       "-O0 -g -m32")


# Declare all source files the target consists of:

SET(TARGET_SRC
  ${TARGET}.cc
# You can specify additional files here!
  fortran_subroutine.f
  )

# Usually, you will not need to modify anything beyond this point...

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.8)

FIND_PACKAGE(deal.II 8.0 QUIET
  HINTS ${deal.II_DIR} ${DEAL_II_DIR} ../ ../../ $ENV{DEAL_II_DIR}
  )

IF(NOT ${deal.II_FOUND})

  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "\n"
    "*** Could not locate deal.II. ***\n\n"
    "You may want to either pass a flag -DDEAL_II_DIR=/path/to/deal.II to cmake\n"
    "or set an environment variable \"DEAL_II_DIR\" that contains this path."
    )

ENDIF()

DEAL_II_INITIALIZE_CACHED_VARIABLES()

PROJECT(${TARGET} C CXX Fortran)

DEAL_II_INVOKE_AUTOPILOT()
```